# No default selected row in DevExpress WinForms GridView in multiselect mode

Tags: gridview, devexpress, multiset

I have a WinForms DevExpress GridControl with single simple gridview in multiselect mode. There is no default selected row when it displayed first time. In singleselect mode all works fine. GridControl obtains data for displaying via binding. May be, it's a bug? Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

After the grid is data bound can't you just set FocusedRowHandle = 0 if the row count > 0?

Comment: It might not have been useful to Pavel, but it was to me; thank you.